# cannot import VisualRecognitionV3

Tags: python, importerror

Here is the python code

```
import os, json, requests
from flask import Flask, jsonify

from watson_developer_cloud import VisualRecognitionV3 as VisualRecognition

def Welcome():

    v = json.loads(os.getenv('VCAP_SERVICES'))
    svcName = 'watson_vision_combined'
    svc = v[svcName][0]['credentials']
    url = svc['url']
    apikey = svc['api-key']

    visual_recognition = VisualRecognition(api_key=apikey)
    print(json.dumps(visual_recognition.list_classifiers(), indent=2))
    with open('./text.png', 'rb') as image_file:
        print(json.dumps(visual_recognition.recognize_text(image_file),  indent=2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = os.getenv('VCAP_APP_PORT', '5000')
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(port),debug=True)
```

Here is requirement.txt

```
Flask>=0.10.1
watson_developer_cloud
requests>=2.0
pip>=8.1.1
```

Here is part of run time log

> 6/6/2016 1:16:56 PM   OUT DEA Starting app instance (index 0) with guid
>   a779e5d9-b5ac-4400-9941-01c1588898c3
>
> 6/6/2016 1:17:13 PM   ERR App Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> 6/6/2016 1:17:13 PM   ERR App File "simple.py", line 4, in
>
> 6/6/2016 1:17:13 PM   ERR App from watson_developer_cloud import
>   VisualRecognitionV3 as VisualRecognition
>
> 6/6/2016 1:17:13 PM   ERR App ImportError: cannot import name
>   'VisualRecognitionV3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like VisualRecognitionV3 has been merged in at this point in time:

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/pull/62/files

However, you can install the development branch:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk@visual-recognition-v3
```

Comment: How can I install this in Bluemix Devop services where the application is created using Cloud Foundry Apps?

Comment: That branch has now be merged and tagged in the 0.13.0 release and uploaded to pypi